# lightning:dataTable controller having attributesTypes for Date is not working as expected

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
component.set('v.equipmentColumns', [
          **{label: 'Predicted Time', fieldName: 'Prediction_Time__c', type: 'Date', typeAttributes:{year:'numeric',month:'short',day:'2-digit'}}**,
          {label: 'Origin Station', fieldName: 'Origin_Station__c', type: 'text', sortable: true},
          {label: 'Destintion Station', fieldName: 'Destination_Station__c', type: 'text', sortable: true},
      ]);
```

currently it is displaying : 2018-03-15T17:37:00.000Z

I need only date from this 2018-03-15

Comment: It's "date", not "Date", if I recall correctly. Whenever you're doing something in Lightning, assume that the case sensitivity of a name or string is significant.

Comment: Thankyou Brian...It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, the "type" attribute is case-sensitive, as are most things in Lightning. `Date` is an unrecognized value, so it defaults to `text`, while `date` is a recognized value that formats a value as a date. When reading any documentation regarding Lightning, assume that whatever is in the documentation is a case-sensitive value and must be precisely the right case or you'll get unexpected results.